# SharePoint Never ask for Sign In once I Sign In using ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-2013, adfs3.0

We had asked someone to setup a ADFS 3.0 and SharePoint 2013. He has completed the work. When I go to login page of SharePoint I can see two options

1. Windows Authentication
2. ADFS

If I select ADFS for the first time the browser prompts me for user name and password. I am able to login correctly using ADFS. However when I try to log-out I am taken back to the sign in page but from then on ADFS/SharePoint stops prompting me for user name and password if I try to login again. This happens until I do no clear my cache and browser history. 
I have reported this to the admin but he says that this is the expected behavior due kerberos token. I do not know much about ADFS and SharePoint. I will much appreciate if someone can let me know if this is the expected behavior of ADFS and SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, this would be expected behavior because the first time you log in you get a FedAuth cookie from SharePoint. That cookie allows you to bypass the subsequent logins. When you clear you browser cache, you are deleting the cookie. See this article here for more info:

[Setting the Login Token](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/setting-the-login-token-expiration-correctly-for-sharepoint-2010-saml-claims-users/)